# How can I improve my product photos of flat, wooden objects?

Tags: product-photography

[image: Large]
[image: Smaller]

I don't know if the light reflections are this bad (What would you say?) but I can change the position of my camera to remove those. Could a lightbox improve the quality of my photos? Other thoughts are welcome!

Comment: This is a good question, but the title is really vague. Could you make it more specific to your particular problem?

Comment: What purpose do the images serve? Is it to sell the products? Where are they being sold? Is it for a ping pong league? I think some context here would be helpful.

Comment: The images provided are necessary for the understanding of the question and answers. Please do not delete them.

Answer (score 4):

If the purpose of these photgraphs is a catalog, don't change anything: **they're close to perfect!** I say this as a professional photographer.

Reflections are not "per se" bad. In your case above, the reflection shows nicely how the surface is.

There is no single "correct" way to take product photographs. As a photographer you should play around with the light and the effects of the light. Sometimes a specific reflection is bad, sometimes it is just right. But you (photographer) should have an idea what you want to show.

Regarding the light box, yes a light box will distribute the light more equally. It will inevitably make your products appear more "flat". If your products do have high contrasts, or even have glittering metal surfaces, this may be the best choice. But I don't see this for your shots above.

There's also a significantly cheaper alternative to a light box: Transparent paper, like vellum paper, HERMA Glassine or [Kraft paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft_paper). If you put a big sheet of this paper in front of your light, you can "modulate" the dispersion of the light with the distance from the light to the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a lightbox will help minimize the reflection. I prefer photos that are well illuminated, while keeping reflections as low as possible. Current image is fine, can be better with a lightbox.